# Invoke-Command - Get-WindowsCapability - Access is denied

Tags: windows-10, powershell, group-policy, wsus

is there some new GPO that for Win 10 pro N for workstations 21H2

limits who can install WindowsCapability over Enter-PSSession and Invoke-Command ?

If I try `Enter-PSSession` and then `Get-WindowsCapability -Online -Name "Media.MediaFeaturePack~~~~0.0.1.0"`

or

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName PC1 -ScriptBlock {Get-WindowsCapability -Online -Name "Media.MediaFeaturePack~~~~0.0.1.0"}
```

I get

```
Access is denied.
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Add-WindowsCapability], COMException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Dism.Commands.AddWindowsCapabilityCommand
    + PSComputerName        : PC1
```

If I run it locally at user as "run as admin" an enter my credentials it works.

Before the 21H1 upgrade it worked.
Any idea where my problem is hidden ?